# Spring Data Wrong column name

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using Spring boot 2 and Hibernate 5

My Output from console

```
2020-04-05 19:17:20.087  WARN 3908 --- [nio-8290-exec-1] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [328] milliseconds.
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        adv.t_address
        (created, created_at, state, updated, updated_at, additionalNumber, apartmentNumber, city, country, number, streetName) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-04-05 19:17:29.347  WARN 3908 --- [nio-8290-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
2020-04-05 19:17:29.347 ERROR 3908 --- [nio-8290-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column "additionalnumber" of relation "t_address" does not exist
  Position: 77
2020-04-05 19:17:29.378 ERROR 3908 --- [nio-8290-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "additionalnumber" of relation "t_address" does not exist
```

My column in the entity model

```
@Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
private String additionalNumber;
```

and also I am using this properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

And my question is: why do I not get column "additionalNumber" instead of "additionalnumber"?

This is the log from DB It seems the DB to get stuck on returning

```
2020-04-05 18:41:39.856 UTC [622] STATEMENT:  insert into adv.t_address (created, created_at, state, updated, updated_at, additionalNumber, apartmentNumber, city, country, number, streetName) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11)
rentni_db  |    RETURNING *
```

Comment: does your db table column and model variable name matching.?

Comment: yes model and table column is matching  "additionalNumber" although I get this exception and I don't know Why

Comment: you can see that insert is OK there is correct column name

Comment: have you tried a simple query which could only insert or update additionalNumber rather than trying a huge one.? just to make sure that it is not the issue of your query

Comment: good point I am going to try it

Comment: @sreyas same result :(

Comment: can I see your code.?

Comment: Only this particular method is not working or none of the db ops are working .?

Comment: I think  it is  a global problem when the variable is created by two words for example "apartmentNumber" I got from PSQLException: ERROR: column "apartmentnumber" of relation "t_address" does not exist

Comment: I don't why because the insert seems to be fine ... as you can see in the console output

Comment: I think that camel casing is causing the issue. anyways you can try using `CriteriaBuilder`

Comment: CamelCasing  I am not sure about it because when  if debug "ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl" or "PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl" I always get correct column name

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL follows the rules of SQL. That means all table names and column names will be lowercase, if they are not quoted.

`@Column(name = "ADDITIONALNUMBER", length = 50, nullable = false)
 private String additionalNumber;`

Maybe this can help